# Adding Page Navigation links to PDF document using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to add local navigation links to an existing pdf using itextsharp.
The pdf have a number of pages and have one cover page, on the cover page I would like to add some links like "Go To Summary", "Go To Images".

I am new to itextsharp and having difficulty in achieving this, please advice.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have was trying to add it using PDFSharp, however could not achieve it. Someone suggested itextsharp but I am new to itext so could not understand it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid your question isn't phrased correctly: currently is too generic for StackOverflow. You should be more specific. Your question could be as simple as [this](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/MergeWithToc2) or as complex as [this](http://www.openhealthnews.com/articles/2014/using-open-source-pdf-technology-solve-unstructured-data-problem-healthcare). There's a whole range of possible answers in-between and you shouldn't make us guess.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I would like to know how can I add links to first page of pdf which when clicked should go to specific page in pdf document using PdfAction.GotoLocalPage.